Estimating function values from recurrence relation
I wanted to construct a recurrence relation $x_n = a_1 x_{n-1} + a_2 x_{n-2} + \cdots + a_k x_{n-k}$ from equidistant samples $x$ of a function $f(t)$. By taking $2k$ samples, the coefficients $a$ are the solution to a linear system, e.g. for $k=2$
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ x_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_2 & x_1 \\ x_3 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
When I used the recurrence relation to obatain new samples, I was surprised that the results were exact, as shown in the following figure for $f(t) = \sin t$ with $k=2$, and for $f(t) = 2t - t^2$ with $k=3$.

My question is why does this work? And what determines the recurrence order $k$ needed to reproduce values of a given function?
Just from the black samples, the two functions above look very similar. I also would have expected needing much more than two coefficients to generate values of $\sin t$.
This is the code I used for the figures:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda t: np.sin(t)
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
  
k, step = 2, .5  # recurrence order, sampling distance
tx = np.arange(2*k) * step
x = f(tx)
  
# compute recurrence coefs
a = np.linalg.solve([x[i:i+k] for i in range(k)], x[k:])

plt.plot(t, f(t))
plt.plot(tx, f(tx), 'ok')
  
x = x[k:]  # use the last k values to compute the next one
for i in range(10):
    x_new = np.dot(x, a)
    plt.plot((2*k + i) * step, x_new, 'or')
    x = np.r_[x[1:], x_new]
  
plt.show() 


If the function (at integer points), can be expressed as a solution to a degree $k$ linear recurrence, then $k+1$ sample points) are sufficient to define it. So, do you know the theory of linear recurrence relations, and what their solution sets look like?

@CalvinLin Interesting, but can all functions be expressed as solutions to a recurrence? And why do we need a higher order for $2t-t^2$ than for $\sin t$?

Not all functions can be expressed as solutions to a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, which is why I asked  "do you know the theory of linear recurrence relations, and what their solution sets look like?"  In particular, why does $2t - t^2$ require 3 terms as opposed to 2?

I don't want to repeat what Calvin Lin just said, so I will not tell you most emphatically that you really, really should read about those linear recurrences with constant coefficients. But you should. In the meantime, you may check some functions which can't be expressed like that, just to see the approximation fail miserably. $1\over1+x^2$ will do, I think; so will $\ln x$.
